# Match duplicate value from 2 colums and 1 unique value from 1 column mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, mysql-5.7, having-clause

I have this table, here is my [db Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d854e39a46ca8716d3b033c60c364e34)

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  `ID` VARCHAR(100),
  `Val` VARCHAR(100),
  `Val2` VARCHAR(100),
  `Val3` VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO table1
  (`ID`, `Val`, `Val2`, `Val3`)
VALUES
  ('1','100','200','90'),
  ('2','100','200','10'),
  ('3','100','200','20'),
  ('4','20','100','55'),
  ('5','20','100','10'),
  ('6','112','100','20'),
  ('7','112','100','20'),
  ('8','90','200','90'),
  ('9','30','90','180'),
  ('10','30','90','29');
```

I want the result with this condition

1. Val had to be duplicate AND
2. Val2 had to be duplicate AND

After i got the duplicate value, now i need to check the val3 from the duplicate value if the **value of val3 had unique value from the previous aggregate**

i tried with this query

```
SELECT
    t1.* 
FROM
    table1 t1 
WHERE
    EXISTS (
    SELECT
        1 
    FROM
        table1 
    WHERE
        ID <> t1.ID 
        AND Val = t1.Val 
        AND Val2 = t1.Val2 
    ) 
    AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
        1 
    FROM
        table1 
    WHERE
        Val = t1.Val 
        AND Val2 = t1.Val2 
    AND Val3 IN ( 
    SELECT Val3 
    FROM table1 
    GROUP BY Val3 
    HAVING count( * ) > 1 
    ) 
)
```

I expect the result would be like this

```
ID  Val Val2    Val3
1   100 200 90
2   100 200 10
3   100 200 20
4   20  100 55
5   20  100 10
9   30  90  180
10  30  90  29
```

BUt i got the result like this

```
ID  Val Val2    Val3
9   30  90  180
10  30  90  29
```

Sample 2

```
INSERT INTO table1
  (`ID`, `Val`, `Val2`, `Val3`)
VALUES
  ('1','100','200','90'),
  ('2','100','200','10'),
  ('3','100','200','20'),
  ('19','100','200','20'),
  ('4','20','100','55'),
  ('5','20','100','10'),
  ('6','112','100','20'),
  ('7','112','100','20'),
  ('8','90','200','90'),
  ('9','30','90','180'),
  ('10','30','90','29');
```

Expected result 2

```
ID  Val Val2    Val3
1   100 200 90
2   100 200 10
4   20  100 55
5   20  100 10
9   30  90  180
10  30  90  29
```

[dbfiddle 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=50ac95459248273903fc9a2381d5efc1)

Sample 3

```
INSERT INTO table1
  (`ID`, `Val`, `Val2`, `Val3`)
VALUES
  ('1','100','200','aa'),
  ('2','100','200','aa'),
  ('3','100','200','aa'),
  ('19','100','200','ab'),
  ('4','20','100','SD2'),
  ('5','20','100','SD1'),
  ('6','112','100','aa'),
  ('7','112','100','ab'),
  ('8','90','200','aa'),
  ('9','30','90','SF2'),
  ('10','30','90','SF1');
```

Expected result 3

```
ID  Val Val2    Val3

4   20  100 SD2
5   20  100 SD1
6   112 100 aa
7   112 100 ab
9   30  90  SF2
10  30  90  SF1
```

Some people might be confused with sample 3, so here is a notes for sample 3 :

For this case, ID 19 in sample 3 had same value with column val and val2 for id 1, 2, 3 ( 100 and 200), but these id (1, 2, 3) had same `aa` value in `val3`, so id 1,2,3 must be excluded, because these id did not match with last condition (val, val2, val3) is unique. ID 19 is fine but `val` dan `val2` column that had duplicate value which is id 1,2,and 3 had already excluded, it makes id 19 had no duplicate value for both column val and val2. if there was another data like '200','100','200','ae' in sample 3, the id 19 will included in result because it has duplicate value beside id 1,2,and 3.

for sample 3 ID 19 will be included if the data in table1 were like this

Sample 3 ( different case )

```
INSERT INTO table1
  (`ID`, `Val`, `Val2`, `Val3`)
VALUES
  ('1','100','200','aa'),
  ('2','100','200','aa'),
  ('3','100','200','aa'),
  ('19','100','200','ab'),
  ('200','100','200','ae'),
  ('4','20','100','SD2'),
  ('5','20','100','SD1'),
  ('6','112','100','aa'),
  ('7','112','100','ab'),
  ('8','90','200','aa'),
  ('9','30','90','SF2'),
  ('10','30','90','SF1');
```

The expected result will be like this

```
ID  Val Val2    Val3

4   20  100 SD2
5   20  100 SD1
19  100 200 ab
200 100 200 ae
6   112 100 aa
7   112 100 ab
9   30  90  SF2
10  30  90  SF1
```

Comment: Why are these varchars?

Comment: it's just datatype, nothing special. @Strawberry

Comment: Why is 3 excluded from the desired result?

Comment: @Strawberry i am sorry looks like i miss that part, i would edit that

Comment: Have to admit, I'm struggling to see how result 3 matches up with data set 3

Comment: @Strawberry i missed som part, edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the table to the queries that apply your conditions:

```
select distinct t.*
from (
  select val, val2
  from table1
  group by val, val2
  having count(*) > 1
) t1 
inner join (
 select val, val2, val3
  from table1
  group by val, val2, val3
  having count(*) = 1
) t2 
on t2.val = t1.val and t2.val2 = t1.val2
inner join (
 select val, val2, val3
  from table1
  group by val, val2, val3
  having count(*) = 1
) t3 
on t3.val = t1.val and t3.val2 = t1.val2 and t3.val3 <> t2.val3
inner join table1 t on t2.val = t.val and t2.val2 = t.val2 and t.val3 in (t2.val3, t3.val3)
```

See [demo1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1adfea3a6671bd34a61d28a36815c1a7), [demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=73615dc2e2f51a616a6edfa9d2e65faf), [demo3](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=00b86a121fc46293cca42957c2311fb2), [demo4](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ddfa0175eea2a64e1452413781d22021).

Comment: for demo 3, the result still not what i expect, i will update some details

Comment: @Gagantous your conclusion is *the id 19 will included in result* Don't you mean by that that id=19 will be included?

Comment: @Gagantous I edited the link for the demo3 and it returns your expected results.

Comment: yes that's definetly what i expect, but when i remove data with id 200 in table1, id 19 still intact in result query, while it has to be excluded because id 19 in final result had no duplicate value

Comment: @Gagantous fine if it worked and don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: i would wait for maybe 2 more days, if there is no other answer, i will marked this as accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, you want rows whose `(val, val2)` tuple is not unique, and whose `(val, val2, val3)` is unique.

Here is one way to express this by filtering the dataset with correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where 
    (
        select count(*) 
        from table1 t2 
        where t2.val = t1.val and t2.val2 = t1.val2
    ) > 1
    and (
        select count(*)
        from table1 t2
        where t2.val = t1.val and t2.val2 = t1.val2 and t2.val3 = t1.val3
    ) = 1
order by id
```

For performance, consider an index on `(val, val1, val2)` (the ordering of columns in the index matters here).

If you are lucky enough to be running MySQL 8.0, this can be phrased more simply and more efficiently using window functions:

```
select id, val, val2, val3
from (
    select 
        t1.*,
        count(*) over(partition by val, val2) cnt_1,
        count(*) over(partition by val, val2, val3) cnt_2
    from table1 t1
) t
where cnt_1 > 1 and cnt_2 = 1
```

Comment: this is the closest i answer i could know, but it seems works!!!

Comment: but from the sample 3, it return false, see this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=238987a7a1acb1a191115d8ab8fb46b9

Comment: @Gagantous: the row with id `19` seems to match the conditions you described, why don’t you want it in the resultset?

Comment: even tho id 19 in sample 3 had same value with column `val` and `val2` for id 1, 2, 3 ( 100 and 200), but these id had same  `aa` value in `val3`, so id 1,2,3 must be excluded, because these id did not match with last condition `(val, val2, val3) is unique.` ID 19 is fine but `val` dan `val2` column that had duplicate value which is id 1,2,and 3 had already excluded, it makes id 19 had no duplicate value for both column `val` and `val2`. if there was another data like `'200','100','200','ae'` in sample 3, the id 19 will included in result because it has duplicate value beside id 1,2,and 3

Comment: okay i have added some notes and another condition for sample 3

Answer (score 1):

As @GMB told in rather simplified manner in his answer, you want rows whose `(val, val2)` tuple is not unique, and whose `(val, val2, val3)` is unique.

Following query should accomplish that very easily:

```
   select t.*
from table1 t
inner join
(
select t1.val, t1.val2
from table1 t1
 inner join
  (select val,val2,val3
    from table1
    group by val,val2,val3
    having count(val3) = 1
  ) t2
 on t1.val = t2.val and t1.val2 = t2.val2 and t1.val3 = t2.val3
 group by t1.val, t1.val2
 having count(distinct t1.id) > 1
) tmp
on tmp.val = t.val and tmp.val2 = t.val2
inner join
(select val,val2,val3
    from table1
    group by val,val2,val3
    having count(val3) = 1
  ) t3
 on t.val = t3.val and t.val2 = t3.val2 and t.val3 = t3.val3
```

Please find the fiddle link for [Sample1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=934fa669c7635271166b50a7ecdbdfb6), [Sample2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=7c8f72fd07356c188974d3ac77230737), [Sample3](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ff6b29fbc09cee318a8086353634fa18) and [Sample4](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=44195888b83fa3a97305c8d89a47bc2d).

Comment: if i used the sample 3, the result is not what i expect, see this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b515259c3d06e82d310bde28f2d281ed

Comment: I have updated the answer & added fiddle demo for all the 4 sample data. Please have a look once.